# Acces a multidimensional array from database and save it

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that I get from a database. It looks like that:

```
arrayDB = [url1,name1,url2,name2,url3,name3, ...]
```

Now I want to save this array within my code. I tried:

```
function symbolsArray(syms){
    var tableArray = [];
    var tableArray2 = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < syms.length; i++) {
        tableArray[i] = syms[i][0]; //url
        tableArray2[i] = syms[i][1]; //Name
    }
}
```

However, this approach is not really suitable because I would need two return values. Is there maybe a better approach or a way to solve the content in a 2D array?

Syms is the data from the database.

Comment: Your `arrayDB` looks like a 1D array to me. Unless your array is made up of sub-arrays who have actual values then it's a 1D array. Also, is `syms` the data from the database? Why do you need to copy it into different arrays?

Comment: your code doesnt work or your arrayDB is wrong ( may [[url1,name1],[url2,name2]] ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do take a look at 
[How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

that answers similar question about 2d arrays in javascript. Try something like-

```
function symbolsArray(syms){
    var tableArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < syms.length; i++) {
        tableArray[i] = [syms[i][0] , syms[i][1]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have seen it but wasn't able to adapt it to my code. Your approach seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not two dimensional.You can seperate urls and names like this...

```js
arrayDB = ['url1','name1','url2','name2','url3','name3'];//assumed array
urls = [];//array for urls
names = [];//array for names
for(i=0;i<arrayDB.length;i++){
 (i%2==0)?urls.push(arrayDB[i]):names.push(arrayDB[i]);
}
console.log(names);
console.log(urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

If ive got you right, your problem is that your code needs to return two things, but return does just one, right?

May Return an Object:

```
return {names: tableArray2,urls:tableArray};
```

You could use it like this:

```
var mydata=symbolsArray(arrayDB);
console.log(mydata.names,mydata.urls);
```

If you just want to deep clone, do:

```
var cloned=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayDB));
```

Or more elegantly:

```
var cloned=arrayDB.map(el=>el.map(e=>e));
```